# csv data parsing issue with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk

I'm trying to upload `csv` file into logstash.

My csv file has more than `200+` rows, in that one row for the reference given below.

```
$ cat report.csv

school_code,student_number,join-date,stu-id,school-type,other-details
12345,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.
[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.
[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.
[City Zipcode#] 012345678
[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.
[Department] Staff services.
[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.
[Services and resources] ADA information.
[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.

Activities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access
***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****
"
```

And my `logstash conf` file as follows.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/app.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline { 
    pattern => '^"'
    negate => "true"
    what => "next"
     }
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["school_code", "student_number", "join-date", "stu-id", "school-type", "other-details"]
      }
    mutate {
      gsub => ["message", '"', '', "message", "\r\n", '']
      strip => ["message", "message"]
     }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
     hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
     index => "school-data"
     document_id => "%{school_code}"
      }
stdout {}
}
```

In `logstash log` it shows `CSV column header value` instead of loading the `actual` value.

```
logstash         | {
logstash         |               "message" => "school_code,student_number,join-date,stu-id,school-type,other-details12345,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.[City Zipcode#] 012345678[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.[Department] Staff services.[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.[Services and resources] ADA information.[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.Activities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****",
logstash         |            "@timestamp" => 2023-06-30T06:15:32.602789093Z,
logstash         |                  "host" => "06605347d1f9",
logstash         |                  "tags" => [
logstash         |         [0] "multiline"
logstash         |     ],
logstash         |         "school_code" => "school_code",
logstash         |          "join-date" => "join-date",
logstash         |     "student_number" => "student_number",
logstash         |              "@version" => "1",
logstash         |                  "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/app.csv",
logstash         |                  "stu-id" => "stu-id",
logstash         |        "school-type" => "school-type",
logstash         |           "other-details" => "other-details"
logstash         | }
```

csv filter has parsed the values from the header row and ignored the remaining columns. It is not expected result.

`skip_header => true` in filter couldn't help.

Can you advise how to upload my csv file data into logstash? My `other-details` column contains of double quotes, spaces & special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

It seems like on the first iteration you match multiline match the line with the header and the lines with the actual information for the first row.

## Solution;

### Set up

Here is my `log.csv` file

```
school_code,student_number,join-date,stu-id,school-type,other-details
111111,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.
[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.
[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.
[City Zipcode#] 012345678
[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.
[Department] Staff services.
[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.
[Services and resources] ADA information.
[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.

Activities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access
***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****
"
222222,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.
[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.
[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.
[City Zipcode#] 012345678
[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.
[Department] Staff services.
[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.
[Services and resources] ADA information.
[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.

Activities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access
***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****
"
333333,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.
[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.
[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.
[City Zipcode#] 012345678
[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.
[Department] Staff services.
[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.
[Services and resources] ADA information.
[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.

Activities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access
***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****
"
```

#### Solution

Here is the full pipeline configuration

```rb
input {
   file {
    path => "/tmp/log.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^([0-9]+,)"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
      auto_flush_interval => 1
    }
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["school_code", "student_number", "join-date", "stu-id", "school-type", "other-details"]
      skip_header => true
  }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

#### Results

Which yield the following.

```rb
{
            "stu-id" => "frank.van",
           "message" => "111111,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\"",
               "log" => {
        "file" => {
            "path" => "/tmp/log.csv"
        }
    },
          "@version" => "1",
              "host" => {
        "name" => "22966421108c"
    },
    "student_number" => "778890",
         "join-date" => "30-12-2022",
     "other-details" => "[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n",
       "school_code" => "111111",
       "school-type" => "Private",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ],
        "@timestamp" => 2023-07-03T15:26:06.499256031Z,
             "event" => {
        "original" => "111111,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\""
    }
}
{
            "stu-id" => "frank.van",
           "message" => "222222,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\"",
               "log" => {
        "file" => {
            "path" => "/tmp/log.csv"
        }
    },
          "@version" => "1",
              "host" => {
        "name" => "22966421108c"
    },
    "student_number" => "778890",
         "join-date" => "30-12-2022",
     "other-details" => "[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n",
       "school_code" => "222222",
       "school-type" => "Private",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ],
        "@timestamp" => 2023-07-03T15:26:06.501637778Z,
             "event" => {
        "original" => "222222,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\""
    }
}
{
            "stu-id" => "frank.van",
           "message" => "333333,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\"",
               "log" => {
        "file" => {
            "path" => "/tmp/log.csv"
        }
    },
          "@version" => "1",
              "host" => {
        "name" => "22966421108c"
    },
    "student_number" => "778890",
         "join-date" => "30-12-2022",
     "other-details" => "[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n",
       "school_code" => "333333",
       "school-type" => "Private",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ],
        "@timestamp" => 2023-07-03T15:26:07.972278609Z,
             "event" => {
        "original" => "333333,778890,30-12-2022,frank.van,Private,\"[S-Name] Frank Van Puffelen.\n[Area/Pin] San Francisco, CA.\n[Locality/Status/Population] Northern California.\n[City Zipcode#] 012345678\n[Relevant Details] Center for flagship.\n[Department] Staff services.\n[Peninsula] Pacific Ocean.\n[Services and resources] ADA information.\n[Created By] Alvaro Alfaro.\nActivities:Transportation,Parking:All_Access\n***** Apply Online: https://stuedu.org/sfg/7894561123*****\n\""
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew the skip_header is not working, that is why I told you to remove the line :D

Comment: With above codec it splits into multiple events and it shows following errors. message" => "\"\r",
logstash         |           "tags" => [
logstash         |         [0] "_csvparsefailure"

Comment: I made it work on my side. I need to provide more details ... tell me it does not work really does not help me help you

Comment: Cab you take a look and suggest? It would be great help.

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. I can't help. Please provide the exact content of the file

Comment: Please refer question section, had updated with actual csv content and your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the logstash version that you are using

Comment: 8.7 or 8.8 what about you ?

Comment: 8.1, will upgrade to 8.8 and check. Thanks

Comment: it does work with 8.1, on my side